Insert ws-addressing in request header web services c#
Good morning, can you please help me, how can I enable ws-addressing in a web service so that they appear in the request header?
`<wsa:Action>`
`<wsa:MessagID>`
`<wsa:To>....`


My code in c#.
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]

    public class WebService1 : WebService
    {
        public ActionHeader ActionHeader;
        public WebService1()

        {
            ActionHeader = new ActionHeader { Action = "http://test.com.co" };
        }
        [WebMethod]
        [SoapHeader("ActionHeader", Direction = SoapHeaderDirection.In)]
        public string GetTransactionInformationInvoice()
        {
            return "Bienvenido, WebServiceTest";
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Action", Namespace = "wsa")]
    public class ActionHeader : SoapHeader
    {
        [XmlText]
        public string Action { get; set; }
    }
}

I'm using XmlRoot to add the custom attribute however it doesn't take the assigned value
I manage to obtain the wsa:action attribute in the header but it does not take the value that I assign, it remains "e gero" instead of http://test.com.co
`<wsa:Action>e gero</wsa:Action>`

As a result I must obtain the wsa attributes with their respective values ​​in the request header, for example
<wsa:Action>http://www.test.com.co</wsa:Action>

I need the same function that SoapUI has with "Enable/Disable WS-A address"
to use the
<wsa:Action> 

tag but directly in the code
